# Docker using almost 8gb without any container running

Tags: linux, docker, docker-desktop

I am using ubuntu 22(Linux blah-laptop 5.15.0-43-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 12 10:30:17 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux), and docker started to use too much memory (almost 8Gb) even without any container running.

When I kill docker desktop I can free the memory, so I guess I am missing some configuration/optimization?!
Here some details:

```
Tasks: 397 total,   2 running, 395 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  2.8 us,  1.4 sy,  0.0 ni, 95.8 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :  15623.0 total,    232.4 free,   4956.7 used,  10433.9 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   1404.2 total,   1011.5 free,    392.8 used.   1854.7 avail Mem 

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                                     
   3211 blah    20   0 6267844 273440 119828 R  25.0   1.7   0:27.97 /usr/bin/gnome-shell                                                                                                                        
   8092 blah    20   0   13540   4516   3404 R  12.5   0.0   0:00.02 top -c                                                                                                                                      
   3875 blah    20   0   22.5g  60400  42916 S   6.2   0.4   0:03.08 /usr/share/docker-desktop/frontend/Docker Desktop --name=dashboard --enable-crashpad                                                        
   8059 blah    20   0 9656992   7.8g   7.8g S   6.2  51.0   0:07.74 qemu-system-x86_64 -accel kvm -cpu host -machine q35 -m 7811 -smp 6 -kernel /usr/share/docker-desktop/linuxkit/kernel -append page_poison=+
```

Docker vesion:

```
Client:
 Version:           20.10.14
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.16.15
 Git commit:        a224086
 Built:             Thu Mar 24 01:45:09 2022
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           desktop-linux
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Desktop 4.8.0 (77103)
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.14
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.16.15
  Git commit:       87a90dc
  Built:            Thu Mar 24 01:46:14 2022
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     true
 containerd:
  Version:          1.5.11
  GitCommit:        3df54a852345ae127d1fa3092b95168e4a88e2f8
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.3
  GitCommit:        v1.0.3-0-gf46b6ba
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: It might not be directly useful to you, but as a piece of additional information, I had a problem with Docker Desktop using a lot of memory through my WSL2 windows integration, and I solved it by limiting the WSL2 configuration through a .wslconfig file to limit it to 4GB and it worked. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config#configure-global-options-with-wslconfig). It could be a Docker Desktop / integration config for you as well on the Linux side.

Comment: thanks to your comment, I realize docker desktop has settings where I can define this. I know it is embarrassing I didn't even think about looking in there... Thanks again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an option on Docker Desktop settings, to limit the use of resources.
I didn't see that (silly me). Fixed now.
[image]

Comment: Why is docker using up RAM when no container is running though? "RAM 3.15GB" "VM memory usage" says at the bottom left.